# how to connect to multiple aws resources using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

If one needs to connect to multiple AWS resources like dynamodb, sns, ec2 etc do we need to create separate boto3 instances for each of them or are there other ways ?
at the moment am doing as show below ...

```
ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
sns= boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is perfectly correct.

When you make a call to the service, your code would use `ddb.function()` or `sns.function()`.

Also, please note that there is a difference between `.resource` and `.client`. Basically, `.client` mirrors the official AWS API, while `.resource` provides a Python object that represents a service. You can choose whichever access method you prefer.